# Veracode CWE 404 - Improper release of resources

Tags: c#, resources, using, veracode

I have a code block that looks like this:

```
using (MemoryStream outputZip = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipOutputStream zipstream = new ZipOutputStream(outputZip))
    {
        zipstream.Password = req.password;
        zipstream.SetLevel(3);
        foreach (var doc in loadocs)
        {
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(doc.FileName);
            zipstream.PutNextEntry(entry);
            zipstream.Write(doc.FileData, 0, doc.FileData.Length);
        }

        zipstream.CloseEntry();
        zipstream.IsStreamOwner = false;
    }
    response.result = new Document()
    {
        name = doc1.Custodian + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString().Replace('/', '_').Replace(':', '_') + ".zip",
        content = outputZip.ToArray()
    };
}
```

I keep getting back

> CWE 404 - Improper resource shutdown or release

pointing to the first line.  Shouldn't the using statement take care of disposing of the object when it is completed?  I can't seem to mitigate this error no matter what I do. I have tried to wrap everything up in `try/catch/finally` and dispose of `outputZip` in the finally but same error results pointing to declaration of `outputZip`.

I have updated my code to look like this:

```
 MemoryStream zipOutput = new MemoryStream();
                    try
                    {
                        ZipOutputStream zipstream = new ZipOutputStream(zipOutput);
                        try
                        {

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            zipstream = null;
                            zipstream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        zipOutput = null;
                        zipOutput.Close();
                    }
```

I am still seeing the Improper resource shutdown or release on the MemoryStream.  Although very redundant doesn't this code actually release the resource?

Comment: You seem to be using old software that does not know of the `using` statement in c#. Your code is fine, the error is not. VS also has this issue on some of the warnings you can set up on FxCop

Comment: The software that this is running through is veracode - I'm not sure we have the ability to ignore this warning as it is a third party service.